# How to read a ContextVar from inside a signal handler

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to read a `ContextVar` from inside a signal handler, but regardless of where I set it, I always get a `LookupError` exception when I try to access it. I guess the problem is that there are two different contexts in use. The code below throws the `LookupError` exception when `SIGINT` is raised. How can I fix this code so that my event is correctly set from inside the signal handler?

```py
import asyncio
import signal
import contextvars

shutdown = contextvars.ContextVar('shutdown')

async def main_task():
    # create a shutdown event
    shutdown.set(asyncio.Event())
    # create a task that waits on the shutdown event
    tasks = [asyncio.create_task(shutdown.get().wait())]
    # wait for that task to complete
    await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

def shutdown_handler():
    # set the event inside the shutdown context variable
    # LookupError: <ContextVar name='shutdown' at 0x7fe34c9e5d60>
    shutdown.get().set()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    event_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    event_loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, shutdown_handler)
    event_loop.run_until_complete(main_task())
    event_loop.close()
```

Comment: The intended use case for context vars is tracking task-local "globals" (asyncio equivalent of thread-locals) and preserving them through callbacks originating in a particular task. Since the signal handler is not spawned off the main task, it makes sense that you don't get the shutdown event when looking for it in the context var. And most importantly: your shutdown event is fully global by nature, so why not just put it into a global variable? Global variables have a bad rap generally, but this kind of usage is exactly what they exist for.

Comment: I think this was my initial approach but I got an exception due to initializing the event at global scope, i.e., with `asyncio.Event()` and then awaiting on that event from inside a coroutine (I'll have to double check this though). In any case, how can I modify this code so that I can await on SIGINT from inside a coroutine?

Comment: You can work around that by setting `shutdown` to `None` at top-level and actually initializing it from `main_task` with `global shutfown; shutdown = asyncio.Event()`.

Comment: *how can I modify this code so that I can await on SIGINT from inside a coroutine* - Your code is fine (once you switch to a simple global), you don't need to modify it. Ok, you can get rid of the `asyncio.wait()` because you just wait for one thing, so `await shutdown.wait()` is sufficient.